# Records Repeating with similar Data

Tags: sql, vb.net, join, sql-server-ce

[image: Image to show Database structure and relations]

I have this situation here as shown in above image. I am developing a inventory system and i need to retrieve the Transaction records. All tables are related with Primary-Foreign relations and are connected using `INNER JOIN`.

Currently when the query fires, i am getting all the records for Purchase Order. I need to retrieve records for Transaction. e.g. For this purchase order in image, i made only two transactions and I want only two record as a result for transaction. I know i can use `OUTER JOINS`to do that and i tried it but didn't get proper results.

Anyone have any idea ?

And here is the actual query :

`SELECT        tblPurchaseMain.Purchase_Main_ID, tblPurchaseMain.Purchase_Date, tblPurchaseMain.TotalAmount, tblSupplier.Supplier_Name, tblPurchaseDetail.Purchase_Detail_ID, tblPurchaseDetail.Quantity, 
                         tblPurchaseDetail.Rate, tblPurchaseDetail.Amount, tblProduct.Product_Name, tblProductCategory.Product_Category_Name, tblTransaction.Transaction_Date, tblTransaction.Transaction_Amount, 
                         tblTransaction.Transaction_Mode
FROM            tblPurchaseTransaction INNER JOIN
                         tblPurchaseMain ON tblPurchaseTransaction.Purchase_Main_ID = tblPurchaseMain.Purchase_Main_ID INNER JOIN
                         tblPurchaseDetail ON tblPurchaseMain.Purchase_Main_ID = tblPurchaseDetail.Purchase_Main_ID INNER JOIN
                         tblSupplier ON tblPurchaseMain.Supplier_ID = tblSupplier.Supplier_ID INNER JOIN
                         tblTransaction ON tblPurchaseTransaction.Transaction_ID = tblTransaction.Transaction_ID INNER JOIN
                         tblProduct INNER JOIN
                         tblProductCategory ON tblProduct.Product_Category_ID = tblProductCategory.Product_Category_ID ON tblPurchaseDetail.Product_ID = tblProduct.Product_ID`

Comment: By the way, if didn't explained properly, please help me do that.

Comment: Please post bigger image. We can't read your query.

Comment: I can't see the image's text, too small.

Comment: Ok. Let me edit and repost the image.

Comment: Or rather, copy and paste the text instead/also of the image!

Comment: What fields do you want in your results? Only columns from tblPurchaseTransaction? BTW: You should show your query and results as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Outer Joins are there to get data from one table even when there is no data in the other. Get orders even when they are not part of a transaction. Get transactions even when they contain no orders. I don't think that is what you need here. Outer Joins have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Question Edited with Query.

Comment: Here is the link to Bigger Size Image : [](http://i.imgur.com/N26ZPBe.png?1)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : As per records shown in above image, i want only two records as results which shows Transaction amount uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are joining things that are not related.

You have two transactions for the single purchase main entry but you have four purchase detail entries.

There doesn't seem to be a valid relationship between the transaction and the purchase details so SQL Server is basically showing you every purchase detail record for each transaction.

You either need to remove the purchase detail and product from your query or add a relationship between transaction and purchase detail.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tag your DBMS. I suppose it is MySQL you are using? Because there is an **ON clause missing** in your query, and MySQL is the only DBMS I know of that doesn't report this error, but silently converts the INNER JOIN into a **CROSS JOIN** instead. Fix this error and see if this solves your problem.

If you still get more rows than you want, let's look at this more closely: Your datamodel let's you have both many purchases per transaction and many transactions per purchase. So if you want one result record per transaction, then you must **GROUP BY** transaction and think about what **aggregated** fields to show. For one transaction this could be `SUM(tblPurchaseMain.TotalAmount)` for instance. However, be aware that you might still be showing duplicate amounts implicitely, as the same purchase can be in several transactions. (E.g. purchase 1 with a total amount of 100$ is connected to transactions A and B. So you would show A 100$ and B 100$.) So maybe you don't want to show `tblPurchaseMain.TotalAmount` at all or maybe even your datamodel is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It isn't MySQL. I am using SQL Compact 4.0 as a database. As per your post, does SQLCe silently converts `INNER JOIN` into `CROSS JOIN` ?

Well i tried to use `Group By` as well as `Distinct` but not with `SUM()` function. I'll use that and revert back. Thanks

Comment: I don't know SQLCe. Your query should through an error, because you want to INNER JOIN tblProduct, but don't specify the criteria with an ON clause. However, I just notice that the ON clause *is* there, only not in the right place (there are two ON clauses on tblProductCategory). Move the ON clause to the right place. This may or may not alter your results.

Comment: Nope. Query works just fine. I posted and Image with results too so the query works but i am not getting desired results.

Comment: If you want to show one line per transaction, there can be multiple purchases and products involved. So for every field you show, you must decide which. The transaction's latest purchase? Or the first? The one with the highest amount? A sum for all amounts involved? Of the products involved; the one that comes first or last in the alphabet? The one that makes for the highest amount in the transaction? The one that is bought most often in general? ...

Comment: As to the query: I am just saying it is syntactically incorrect. You should correct it, even if the dbms let pass your error silently. You never know whether your syntax error effects results.

Answer (score -1):

it could be due to your table linking, you may try adding the keyword DISTINCT to your select statement see example below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1,FIELD2 from TABLE
```

Comment: some fields in your select statement have unique values. I cant see the image clearly

Comment: Please refer image link in above comments.

Comment: i think it's because of your link to the table tblPurchaseDetail, you cannot achieve the 2 rows result if you are linking to this table.

Comment: it is a detail table and have 2 or more rows in it based on your linking. do you really need the fields selected in table tblPurchaseDetail?

Comment: yes. i want to print a bill for purchase order and will need purchase details